# 1840-1900 Income Data in U.S

Tags: data-request, usa, us-census, income

Does income data exist during the 1840-1900 time period (or any span within in) that is at the micro level? Or was this information never collected in censuses, etc?

Comment: The Census doesn't list it in their list of available economic data (http://www.census.gov/ces/dataproducts/demographicdata.html), but they do mention that they have more data that needs to be recovered.  Data that's more than 72 years old gets released by NARA, not Census, though : http://www.archives.gov/research/census/ ... I think it's microfilm, though.

Comment: you can download microdata with estate assets (not income) for 1850, 1860, and 1870  https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/group?id=income

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like a question on income or earnings was asked as part of the Census during this time period: http://www.census.gov/history/www/through_the_decades/index_of_questions/.